# Changing global variable in separate file

Tags: c, queue, global-variables

I am trying to implement a task scheduler in c where I have the Queue struct and its functions in a separate file like this:

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return 0;
}

Queue* q = NULL;  

int init_LCFS_PR()
{
    // TODO
    if ((q = queue_new(comp))){
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void arrive_LCFS_PR(int id, int length)
{
    // TODO
    def_task a;
    a.id = id;
    a.length = length;

    queue_offer(q, &a);
}

def_task *tick_LCFS_PR()
{
    // TODO

    def_task* a_ = queue_poll(q);
    printf("%d %d\n", a_->id, a_->length);

    return NULL;
}
```

My main looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{       
    if (init_LCFS_PR() == 0)
    {
            arrive_LCFS_PR(0, 3);
            arrive_LCFS_PR(1, 6);
            arrive_LCFS_PR(2, 4);

            tick_LCFS_PR();
            tick_LCFS_PR();
            tick_LCFS_PR();
    }
 return 0;
```

The problem is that I am getting following output

```
2 4
2 4
2 4
```

Pulling returns only the last added element when I define the Queue struct in the separate file. But when i define my queue in the main like this:

```
            def_task a;
            a.id = 0;
            a.length = 3;

            def_task b;
            b.id = 1;
            b.length = 6;

            def_task c;
            c.id = 2;
            c.length = 4;

            Queue* q = queue_new(&comp);  
            queue_offer(q, &a);
            queue_offer(q, &b);
            queue_offer(q, &c);

            def_task* a_ = queue_poll(q);
            def_task* b_ = queue_poll(q);
            def_task* c_ = queue_poll(q);

            printf("%d %d\n", a_->id, a_->length);
            printf("%d %d\n", b_->id, b_->length);
            printf("%d %d\n", c_->id, c_->length);
```

,I am getting the expected output.

Comment: The problem is likely in the code you don't show — `queue_offer()`.  You pass a pointer to a local variable to the function; what happens next?  We can't see, but I suspect you store a pointer and do not make a copy.  You're lucky it is behaving as cleanly as it seems to be doing.

Comment: One serious issue: why is the variable `q` a global variable (with external visibility), rather than a `static` variable? Why would another file want to reference this `q` by name? Single-letter global variables are always very dubious. They should have meaningful names, and while `q` is in some ways better than most, it should almost certainly be `static`. Which header declares it? If the answer is 'none', it should be `static`.  In fact, functions should be `static` unless (a) their name is `main()` or (b) there is a header that declares the function and the function is used in another file.